# How can I log text (and see the logs)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, metamask

I'm writing a contract using remix,  and I'm hitting an error but I can't debug it.  When I enter the transaction hash in remix it tells me the json is empty ("").

I'm testing on the ropsten test network and using metamask for may wallet.

Is there a way I can log text and view those logs?

Answer (score 0):

A failed transaction cannot emit an event, because failed == *nothing happened*. This is inconvenient for debugging.

You can check assumptions with `require()` and emit a *reason*. Reasons are observable when the `require()` expression evaluates to false.

There are many reasons why a contract can fail. Some are deliberately caught and emit a reason but others are because of protocol or because further processing isn't possible.

A protocol-level error would be sending more money than the account actually has. You would check on your own that such is not the case. Nothing you can do in the contract to make it more informative because it won't get that far.

Further processing is not possible on divide by zero, accessing an array out of bounds, etc., and those things can be checked with `require()`.

For example:

```
function elementAtIndex(uint row) external view returns(address) {
  require(row < myAddressArray.length, "row is out of range");
  return myAddressArray[row];
}
```

or ...

```
function divider(uint nom, uint denom) extern pure returns(uint) {
  require(denom > 0, "denominator is zero");
  return nom/demon;
}
```

As a general heuristic, try to deliberately catch every error that *can possibly occur*. You can often report what the problem is, and if you get no message, at least you know what the problem *isn't*. When you optimize, remove checks for *impossible* conditions that you might have inserted for debugging purposes, but incline to keeping the informative messages for *possible* situations related to input since it helps everyone understand what's going on.

Hope it helps.